# n_max or nrow argument in read_csv_arrow in R

Tags: r, apache-arrow

I'm surprised but I couldn't find `nrows` or `n_max` arguments in `arrow::read_csv_arrow` document in R.

Am I missing features, or is it simply not implemented?

Is there a quick workaround for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does not support it as an argument, but you can read it *lazily* (not read in everything) by adding `as_data_frame = FALSE`, using `head(.)` (which arrow recognizes efficiently), and *then* `collect()` the data.

```r
write.csv(mtcars, "mt.csv", row.names = FALSE)
arrow::read_csv_arrow("mt.csv", as_data_frame = FALSE) |>
  head(n = 3) |>
  collect()
# # A tibble: 3 × 11
#     mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb
#   <dbl> <int> <dbl> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <int> <int> <int> <int>
# 1  21       6   160   110  3.9   2.62  16.5     0     1     4     4
# 2  21       6   160   110  3.9   2.88  17.0     0     1     4     4
# 3  22.8     4   108    93  3.85  2.32  18.6     1     1     4     1
```

This has the same effect, only the first 3 rows (in this case) are ever read into memory in R.

We know it's not reading in all data ahead of time because of we look at just the output from `read_csv_arrow`, we'll see that it is not a frame, instead an arrow "Table", which is a representation of the data schema but not the data itself:

```r
arrow::read_csv_arrow("mt.csv", as_data_frame = FALSE)
# Table
# 32 rows x 11 columns
# $mpg <double>
# $cyl <int64>
# $disp <double>
# $hp <int64>
# $drat <double>
# $wt <double>
# $qsec <double>
# $vs <int64>
# $am <int64>
# $gear <int64>
# $carb <int64>
```

Comment: Alternatively, ``arrow::open_csv_dataset() %>% head(3) %>% collect()`` can be used.